# How to manage project-wide constants in a project using ROR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, constants

### lib/constant.rb

```
module Constant

  BANQUET_TYPE_OF_OFFER = [['Narrow By Offer Type',''], ["A la Carte", "A la Carte"],

  ["Alcohol Offer", "Alcohol Offer"], ["Buffet", "Buffet"], ["Brunch", "Brunch"], 

  ["Happy Hours", "Happy Hours"], ["Set Menu", "Set Menu"],["Banquets", "Banquets" ]]

end
```

### application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

    include Constant

end
```

### views/banquets/banquet.html.haml

```
= f.select_tag "type_of_offer", options_for_select(Constant::BANQUET_TYPE_OF_OFFER, 
@selected), :name => "banquet[type_of_offer][]", :multiple => true
```

I created many constants in rails application like java constants. This is best practice or not ??? Any other solution is there?

Comment: Why not use yaml and load them with a helper method?

Comment: You shouldn't need the line `include Constant` in your ApplicationController, all files inside your `lib` dir should automatically be included.  (The logic is in `config/application.rb`)

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @Batkins, you don't need to include the module in your class.

When it comes down to constants, it boils down to preferences on using constants defined as Ruby vs. defined as YAML.

Ideally the `BANQUET_TYPE_OF_OFFER` would be defined in the model where it makes more sense and not in a global location. If you definitely have to have it outside your models, think about moving it into `config/initializers/` instead of `lib`.